# Versions of depended-upon artifacts in maven

Tags: maven-2

I am working on an open source project which involves 3 artifacts X, Y, Z where X depends on Y and Y depends on Z.

I made some changes to X, and wanted to give it a local version, so I modified the pom.xml to name the version as, say, 1.0-foo, but I also made sure that during the build, we use version 1.0 of Y, so I have some lines like these

```
<groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
<artifactId>X</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>X Jar</name>
<version>1.0-foo</version>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
  <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I know Y also depends on Z, because if I do "mvn dependency:list" I will get something like this:

```
[INFO]    com.myCom:Y:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    com.myCom:Z:jar:1.0:compile
```

And this has been working for us, until the open source project upgraded to 2.0.  I set up my pom.xml similar to the above (just change "1.0" to "2.0"), but now my build failed, complaining that it could not find Z for the version "2.0-foo".

The error message was something like:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) com.myCom:Z:jar:>2.0-foo

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: ...

  Path to dependency:
        1) com.myCom:X:jar:>2.0-foo
        2) com.myCom:Y:jar:2.0
        3) com.myCom:Z:jar:>2.0-foo
```

I don't understand why now maven thinks Y (of version 2.0) depends on Z version 2.0-foo but not simply 2.0.  What did I do wrong?

I also checked the pom.xml of Y at 1.0.  It says

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
    <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Y</name>
    <url>http://www.myCom.com</url>
    <parent>
      <groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
      <artifactId>A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
        <artifactId>Z</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    ...
```

And that of Y at 2.0 is almost identical:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
    <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Y</name>
    <url>http://www.myCom.com</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myCom</groupId>
            <artifactId>Z</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: did you do `mvn install` for your updated artifacts :X, Y and Z ? can you run `mvn dependency:tree` and post the output ?

Comment: @ben75, Thanks for asking.  For 1.0, "mvn dependency:tree" shows somethings like

`    [INFO] +- com.myCom:Y:jar:1.0:compile`
`    [INFO] |  +- com.myCom:Z:jar:1.0:compile`

For 2.0, both "mvn install" or "mvn dependency:tree" with the same error message complaining could not find Z of version 2.0-foo

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  My project X has a parent for which in its `pom.xml` there is a `dependencyManagement` section which specifies that Y depends on Z with version `${project.version}`, and that was how the version `2.0-foo` was picked up.

I changed the lines in the `dependencyManagement` from `${project.version}` to `${upStreamVersion}`, which was set to `2.0` and the problem was solved.

Thanks for all your help!